# Plotting a function with different ranges in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I would like to plot the following function:

[image: g(x) with different ranges]

I tried this code:

```
x = 0:0-1:4;
x1 = x(x<=-1);
x2 = x(x>-1 & x<=2);
x3 = x(x>2);
y1 = -3;
y2 = 1;
y3 = 4;
plot([x1 x2 x3], [y1 y2 y3])
```

But it is giving me the error that vectors must be the same length. How do I fix this error?

Comment: `plot` is not smart enough to do what you mean, so he's doing what you tell it. Your X vector is empty. Your Y vector is 3 elements long. If you were MATLAB, how you'd draw this? :-)

Comment: And before saying, *oh, I mis-initialized `x`, is `0:0.1:4`, not `0:0-1:4`*, the problem is still there, with different numbers: now X axis has 41 points and Y axis is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that matlab do not understand that `y1=-3` means -3 for each value of `x1`. It needs a vector of -3s with as many elements as `x1`.

One way to define such a vector is the following:

```
x = -4:0.1:4;
x1 = x(x<=-1);
y1 = -3*ones(1,numel(x1));
```

So that you can plot the you want in the following way (look at it after giving it a try):

> figure;hold on 
>  x = -4:0.1:4;
>  x1 = x(x<=-1);
>  y1 = -3*ones(1,numel(x1));
>  plot(x1,y1)
>
>  x2 = x(x>-1 & x<=2);
>  
>  y2 = ones(1,numel(x2));
>  plot(x2,y2)
>
>  x3 = x(x>2);
>  y3 = 4*ones(1,numel(x3));
>  plot(x3,y3)

Comment: This worked out perfectly. What is the purpose of "figure" though?

Comment: [`figure`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html) creates a figure window